# Use custom decorator to add extra fields to TypeGraphQL @ObjectType class

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, graphql-js, typegraphql

Is there a way to create a custom class-level decorator that adds two parameters to a `TypeGraphQL` `@ObjectType` class?

Example:

```js
@ObjectType()
@Timestampable // custom decorator
class User {
    @Field()
    email: string;
}
```

The `@Timestampable` decorator should add the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` props to the `User` class and the new props should show up in the `gql` schema.

I am trying to avoid doing this:

```js
@ObjectType()
@Timestampable
class User {
    @Field()
    email: string;

    @Field(() => Date)
    createdAt: Date;

    @Field(() => Date)
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

If yes, then is it possible to stack multiple decorators like this:

```js
@ObjectType()
@Timestampable
@Blamable
class User {
...
}
```

Do you know a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Please include your attempted solution so far